# Django template variable string as html

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I've written a small view which contains some html embedded into one of the list arrays.  When I use that list item in a template, the data is interpreted by the template as a literal string rather than html.  How do I get django to not ignore html tags inside of a variable?

**views.py**

```
def home(request, username='Pedro'):
    template_name = 'main/index.html'
    url = "https://www.duolingo.com/users/{}".format(username)
    getUserData(url)
    context = {
        'username': username,
        'wordLists': wordlists,
        'explanations': explanations,
        'words': words,
    }
    # print(context)
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def getUserData(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    userdata = response.json()

    for language in userdata['language_data']:
        for index in userdata['language_data'][language]['skills']:
            if index.get('levels_finished') > 0:
                wordList = index.get("words")
                wordlists.append(wordList)
                explanations.append(index.get("explanation"))
                for wordItem in wordList:
                    words.append(wordItem)
```

**template**

```
{% block content %}
  {% for e in explanations %}
    {{ e }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**results**
[image]

Comment: {{ myhtml |safe }}

Comment: May be you can delete this question now :)

Comment: I would but once I worded my question a little differently I was able to find the answer.   :)  It may help others to leave it up.